# How to fix invalid dates in mssql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column, called `date_col`

I would like to fix the invalid dates, for example february 31, and convert them to valid dates.

I tried this:

```
CAST(CAST(date_col AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATETIME)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime
```

Comment: Valid dates like ..what?

Comment: "I would like to fix the invalid dates, for example february 31"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can use ISDate function to check if the data is correct